# How do I use a macro to delete blank cells within a range automatically?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using if-then statements to automatically populate an excel sheet and I would like the cell (not the whole row or column) to automatically delete itself if the equation is false.  I need this to happen automatically so that we can pull these sheets up as a reference quickly without having to delete the blank cells before seeing the results. This is the equation I am currently using:

```
=IF(A1="calcutta",B1,"")
```

The formula does what I would like it to do, but I understand that I will need to run a Macro to automatically delete blank cells withing my range as you cannot delete cells with a formula.  Essentially I would like it to work like this:

```
=IF(A1="calcutta",B1,"deletecell")
```

Can anyone help me with this?  I have never used macros before, so the exact equation would be especially helpful!

Comment: You can delete the formula when the result is empty, granted we can tell you how to do that. BUT are you sure you want to do it only when the result is empty? Be aware that, if you `delete` the formula at some place, but later `A1` is edited and become "calcutta", the formula is gone and you will still have blank. Therefore it makes no sense, unless you want to delete *ALL*  the formulas and keep only the resulting values, whether blank or not.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I would still like to delete it if blank as the blank cells are interfering more with our results than this mistake would.  Knowing that if I change cell A1 I will have  to go back and manually populate B1 would be less of an inconvenience for me than to have to delete the blank cells each time I opened the document.  Thanks!

Comment: Using VBA you can go for the `WorksheetChange` event and check for the cells like `A1:A20` and if the `Taget.Value` is "calcutta" then `Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value` or use `Target.Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1` if column B is not static else set it to be empty. (Assuming the formulas in column C)

Answer (score 0):

After you have entered your formulas, run this short macro:

```
Sub FixFormulas()
    Dim r As Range, BigR As Range
    On Error GoTo tellme
        Set BigR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    For Each r In BigR
        If r.Value = "" Then r.Clear
    Next r
    Exit Sub
tellme:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "no formulas"

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If you want this action to occur automatically **after** you have entered a formula, the use this *Event macro*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Target
            If r.HasFormula And r.Value = "" Then r.Clear
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Comment: A change in the value returned by a formula does not trigger a Worksheet_Change event so Target will never be a formula even if something else triggered the event. A formula only triggers a Worksheet_Change event when it is originally entered or cleared.

Comment: @Jeeped When you **first enter a formula, BOTH** events are raised.......try it..........a pure re-calc will not catch a switch to NULL.